# How We Use Twitter

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As some of you may be aware, we started a Twitter account to promote the site this past weekend: [@cs_educators](https://twitter.com/cs_educators). I am currently managing it, but I would love your input on how we use it: I want it to be a collaborative effort.

Up until now, I have tweeted in general to some hashtags -- #apcsp, #apcsa, #cs4all, #cs50ap -- I know are CS-oriented and have mentioned a few of our more popular threads based on the audience of followers I personally have.

I would like your input on the following:

- How often should we tweet?
- What accounts should we follow?
- What should the general content of our tweets be?
- What additional hashtags should we connect our tweets to?

I can also schedule tweets, so if you have suggestions for a message you'd like to get out there at a particular time, we can always plan ahead.

Answer (score 6):

In my ideal world, we would tweet once a day with either the top-voted question of the day, or some other thought-provoking (or funny) CS Educators statement.  At the beginning, we can slowly run through the questions that we've built up.

Answer (score 2):

As the site grows the numbers might change, but the concepts can remain the same.

I don't know how often to tweet on a schedule, maybe once a day, maybe twice. If others have followed other forums or blogs they might have a metric to base our schedule on.

Aside from the scheduled tweets, I think we should be watching the view count and vote count on the questions and tweet one when it crosses a threshold value. At this point, maybe 15 votes or 50 views. This would create a random posting time throughout the day, and act like a localized version of HNQ.

Picking the question(s) to post for the regular schedule could be done by looking at the ones that seem interesting but still have low counts/views/answers for some reason. Of course, it would be nice if they had already been edited to be clear and clean before the tweet. Obviously the selection of such questions is a manual process, while the random questions above could be automated (though we may not want to do so, keeping in manual for now so that we can *filter* what we tweet while we're trying to grow).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

- We should tweet on some regular basis, and say things that would be interesting for teacher; addressing problems that they most probably faced or are facing.
- Firstly, stack exchange sites. Also, maybe universities and colleges ( perhaps just the cs department).
- I think I answered that in the second point.
- not sure at all about this part.

These answers are in the mindset of getting more people to the site.

EDIT:

I think that we should ask a user whether they mind a if question\answer they posted gets featured on twitter.

Comment: Followed Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow Twitter accounts. Do you have any other specific ones you would recommend?

Comment: @Peter the cs one. just to keep in touch...

Comment: @Peter I think my edit is worth noting.