# Let's create a tweet sandbox!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As you might know, [we have a Twitter account](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/how-we-use-twitter) (@cs_educators), which is currently managed by [Peter](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/peter), one of the pro-tem mods on this site.

In the last months, there hasn't been a lot of activity (the last tweet was from August 2). This has been mentioned several times in chat (e.g. [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/conversation/twitter-activity)). There were ideas to automate tweeting, but currently, it doesn't seem like this will be implemented soon (this is just my impression, please correct me if I'm wrong).

As a compromise between automated tweeting and having nothing, I'd like to propose to create a **tweeet sandbox** here on Meta. In my eyes, this is an easy-to-implement method to lighten Peter's workload and increase the Twitter account's activity.

I think the "tweet sandbox question" should be created by one of the site's moderators. Every answer to the tweet sandbox question would be a possible tweet, and my idea is that hereby the community creates a repository of tweets. When an answer is tweeted, it could be edited (prepending something like "Already tweeted.") so the same tweet isn't set off twice. It might be a good idea to have a moderator convert the sandbox question into a community wiki (see [this FAQ answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/) for details), to lower the reputation threshold required on Meta sites for editing posts.

I guess we should just make sure that it's clear that every contribution to tweet sandbox answers might be posted on the Twitter account - I am not a lawyer, but I could imagine this being necessary to ensure that the poster grants the rights that their content can be reused according to the Twitter Terms Of Service (maybe they should be linked).

What do you think of this idea?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are only 33 followers of the twitter account. I'm guessing they are all members.

In the chat room we have the ability to * a comment and it gets shown in the RHS sidebar. It might also be possible to have a *tweet* function that suggests a comment for a tweet, but probably doesn't actually create the tweet.

HNQ's might also be automatically suggested for a tweet. Or there might be a special button to promote a question as a tweet.

These suggestions depend on UI changes, of course.

Comment: You have a point with the followers argument, I think. My hope is that the account will get new followers if there are more tweets. -- To the UI changes: I've suggested the community wiki sandbox especially because there would be no UI changes to make, as they would require programming effort and I'm not sure if there's anybody currently willing to do this.

Comment: What does "RHS" stand for?

Comment: We are going to be unable to convince SE to these features

Comment: "Auto-tweeting" is actually something we did [in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work), but stopped because it didn't seem to have any effect. You _might_ be able to rig something up to simulate that behavior, but... as already noted here, you'd probably just be preaching to the choir.

Comment: @BenI. as usuall Right Hand Side. He's talking about the star board