# Teachers: share your knowledge

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

Occasionally, there are [crazy question-answer ratios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) because of users who mostly answer questions - these people obviously have tons of knowledge they can share. With this in mind, since we [want to increase the number of questions asked](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/can-this-site-succeed-encouraging-more-users-and-questions), I thought I'd point out that self-answering is **encouraged** by the SE system. So if you came up with a nice solution for a pesky problem - share it. If you thought of a piece of advice you'd give to first-timers - share it. Everyone else will appreciate it, I assure you.

Comment: Good idea, but, if someone's still reticent to ask their own question, they can ask someone else in chat to ask it for them.