# Site promotion needs to be, well, promoted

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So, I think we [missed an opportunity](http://www.csteachers.org/page/2017Conference). Wouldn't this have been a good place to promote the site (I look for something that says we can't or cannot, so I have no idea whether it would have been allowed to use that conference to promote CSE).

With summer's end visible in the foreseeable future (it ***is*** August, isn't it?), I think **now** is the right time to give site promotion higher priority. I'm searching for similar conferences here in Israel (to which I won't go, but rather contact organizers and give them the elevator pitch and hope they agree to help promote the site). This meta post's purpose is twofold:

1. Asking how I might go about promoting the site in front of teachers while I myself am not a teacher (although I know a few, and that might help).
2. Bringing the subject of site promotion back up, now that [Winter is Coming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_Is_Coming). We did a nice job promoting CSE while it was in **private beta**. Now that it's public, we can do much, much better.

Looking at our A51 statistics, it's not difficult to notice a steady decline in the number of visits our site gets. While expected (what with it being summer and all), I wouldn't call it good. August has just begun, so now's the time to, as [Robert put it](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/64/150), *spread the word* (v2.0) (Although he was referring to users, I am talking about other methods of site promotion).

It's been suggested (by many people) that a handy way to draw people to the site is by showing **people** some interesting questions and answers on the site. That's certainly useful. But not only showing it directly to some people, we can find places like [this one](http://www.csteachers.org/page/2017Conference) (except for the fact that it already passed; we should probably try it for ones in the near future `;)`), and show something similar to the tour, which showcases a question and its answer.

We can showcase some interesting questions and their answers.

So, what are some thoughts about Site Promotion, v2.0?

---

After some discussion (literally less than 10 messages) I realized that it would be useful to ask questions about subjects that haven't been covered before in CSE (Lego Mindstorms, Arduino and such), **before** we reach out to relevant communities. That way we'll have something worth showing when we do reach out.

### Update:

I've written an email to someone in Lego Education (haven't sent it yet, I'm reviewing it). Let's hope this works.

Comment: This is the right question. Thank you for posting this!

Comment: @BenI. Going through meta posts all around the network on how to make sites succeed. RC's blog posts are handy

Answer (score 4):

- I think that the Twitter account needs to be used a lot more. Maybe
  participating in the K12 CS Ed Twitter chats
- I think that posting on
  the CS Ed forum for k-12 on Facebook would be a smart plan:
  https://www.facebook.com/groups/CSEdForum/

Comment: Excellent ideas. Thanks!

Comment: An idea might be to create a tweet sandbox community wiki here on meta so the community could prepare tweets - this would probably help us to "generate" more tweets.

Answer (score 3):

We want to show diversity. Advertise to CS students, because they can ask about self-learning. Advertise to coaches of robotics clubs, because they can ask about teaching with arduino, LEGO mindstorms, etc. Advertise to teachers because they can ask about...well...teaching.

So have good questions in all those categories, and then advertise to all of them. I feel like we're targeting this small subset of the people who could really use this site. Target *students*, target *coaches*, target elementary/highschool teachers, target tutors, don't just target CS professors!

Comment: True. I intend to write a letter to LEGO Ed. today to introduce this site.