# Optimistic Suggestion: topic challenge + site promotion +?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, topic-challenges

Looking at the visits/day of our site, it can be better.

170 v/d...

So, maybe this is a good time to look more closely at promoting our site.

I'm not sure how the twitter account is going, and I know the blog isn't getting anywhere ATM (99% my fault, 1% my university's fault), ***but***

Our site *has* been drawing a few HNQ. not too many, but more than 2 lately (IIRC). It feels as though this is a good time to "strike":

Suggestion:

1. Another topic challenge. We should aim for one that'll draw HNQs, but not be controversial. A good, high-quality HNQ.
2. Advertising. I made 2, but I have ~0 "regularity" in those sites. People here who are relatively well known in other communities can<sup>1</sup> promote CSE.SE in those communities. This doesn't only mean Stack Exchange sites, but also relevant Facebook groups, subreddits, instagram pages, twitter and other social media.

   1. Saying something like "I highly recommend checking out [cseducators.se]." And then include a link to a good question, that is particularly relevant to the specific community (i.e. my functional programming vs oop question doesn't fit well in a community of people teaching block based)
   2. Being gently bold is key
3. For those who remember the site promotion during private beta<sup>[2](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/can-this-site-succeed-encouraging-more-users-and-questions), [3](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/65/150)</sup>, contacting friends and colleagues directly is perfect. It's been 8 months<sup>***I almost can't believe that***</sup> since then, and almost everyone here (both from before public beta and after) has met new people, and/or met some people who might benefit from the site (as well as benefit the site). **Tell them**.
4. Finally, this really isn't a community effort if it's only 1 person's suggestion, so:

I'd like to hear what other suggestions/ideas you have, regarding these matters.

---

<sup>1</sup>I really don't want to say *should*, but It'd be very nice if they did
<sup>2</sup>[This](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/can-this-site-succeed-encouraging-more-users-and-questions) meta question, for example
<sup>3</sup>And the last paragraph of [this answer](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/65/150) to that question; this is almost exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Several of us are regularly promoting on Reddit's CSEducator's community, and there have been occasional emails out to the AP Computer Science A community.  I seem to recall that thesecretmaster found another community we should be reaching out to, though I recollect no details about that one.  Membership in communities (such as FRC, APCSA, APCSP, Greenfoot, etc) provides an entry-point to links back to the resources that we have been creating here.

Just like in any other marketing, word of mouth is best.  I know that there has been a fair amount of that, and it has netted us some people (that I know of) who are moderately involved.

In that vein, I've gone to SO from time to time and found posts that are off-topic there but belong here, or found people who are definitely CS educators, and let them know about the site directly.  EllenSpertus came to us that way.  If there are other communities that you are involved in where you see questions that belong here, feel free to leave a comment letting them know that their question would [be / also be] on-topic at this site.